# Ford ka Mk1 (2008) drivers side footwell leak

Tags: ford, leak, water-leak, ka

Water is leaking into the driver's side footwell on my 2008 Ford Ka.

Any ideas on where to start looking to stop this happening? I assume it could be a bulkhead seal/grommet has failed perhaps ?

There is no water leaking into the passenger footwell, only the driver's side.

It's quite a lot of water - if I push the carpet down, water comes up.

It's causing large amounts of condensation on the inside of the windscreen as well.

It is definitely a water leak, not coolant.

Comment: Many times the water that runs down your windshield is gathered in a drainage system that has been blocked by debris - especially leaves.  Are you able to inspect for that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks guys. I know I can rule out some of the possibilities. 1) It's not coming up from the floor, the car is solid underneath (fully rustproofed at 2 years old).
2) It's not from the windscreen seal, I can tell because I sat in the car while it was raining and it was dry all around the inside of the windscreen, this seal is in good condition. Good shout on debris etc - I will check this! At this stage I'm pretty sure it could be bulkhead seals or some other seal from that area...I guess the challenge now is how to access that without a lot of work :/

Answer (score 0):

The places to start looking are:

1) the floor: water gets thrown up and comes through the hole...

2) bulkhead seals and around the wipers / under the shield between the windscreen and bonnet...

3) Windscreen seal, top, side and bottom as the water can run around and then drip down behind the dash...

Finding it: well, we would have one "making rain" with a hose, flooding the roof, windscreen and bonnet while the other looked with a torch to see where the water was coming down. Sometimes removing the carpet was necessary just to see where the water tracks started...

But, you will probably need to remove the carpet to get it dry quickly anyway.